# SOS1 for linearizing complementarity condition

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to linearize the complementarity condition
$0<a \perp b>0$  with SOS1 method by the following formulation:

$p_1+p_2 = 1e5 \label{1}\tag{1}$

$a < p_1\label{2}\tag{2}$

$b < p_2\label{3}\tag{3}$

where, $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the SOS1 variables. If equation \eqref{1} is set to 1, the problem becomes integer infeasible. If i set it to 1e5, both the variables attain values greater than 1. However, the definition of SOS1 says, at the most only 1 variable can take non zero value. Any clarification in this regard will be helpful.

Comment: As i understand, the equality in eq. (1) causes the integer infeasibility. Hence, i reformed the equation to $p_1+p_2 < 1$. In this case,, after the solve $p_1$ is taking a value over 5000 and $p_2$ is taking a value just over 800.

Comment: What are the domains of all the variables (lower and upper bounds, integral or not)? Also, do you mean <= in (2) and (3)? Math programs are generally intolerant of strict inequalities.

Comment: The variables a are indexed with different generation resources with their limits not exceeding 5950. b are Lagrangian dual variables with no upper bound and both a and b have their lower bound set to 0. There is no integral conditions involved. Yes, i meant <=, thank you for pointing that out. I tried big-M method but the optimization results vary depending on the M value.

Comment: I agree that in an SOS1 constraint at most one variable should be nonzero. Is it possible that the solver you are using does not understand or support SOS1 constraints? If it does, I would have to guess that you entered the constraint incorrectly.

Comment: I am using cplex solver which from what I read supports sos1 constraints. Please let me know if that is the case. Also, is it possible that two variables in a sos1 set take positive values, where one of the sos1 variable value takes a higher value and the other takes a significant lower value which essentially set the constraint as binding. I am guessing this is far fetched but I am wondering if there is any truth behind it.

Comment: No, only one variable in an SOS1 constraint can be nonzero (meaning absolute value larger than the constraint tolerance setting, which defaults to something like 10^-6). Yes, CPLEX supports SOS1. Early in the output, during presolve, you should see information about how many SOS1 constraints were in the initial model and how many were left after presolve. Is your SOS1 constraint present after presolve?